# How do I whitelist domain in its home domain in noscript

Tags: firefox, noscript

So lets say I want to whitelist facebook in facebook.com but blacklist it everywhere else. How do I do it? There used to be ABE rules but they got depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ABE rules still exist:

You will find them in NoScript Options, Advanced tab, ABE sub-tab.

Comment: I can't find it. [This is all I see](https://ibb.co/W6Yj7r5)

Comment: Right, it has disappeared from later versions. I forgot that I'm using a XUL-supporting Firefox clone, Pale Moon, which uses NoScript Version 5.1.9. Works just as well.